# Django Migrations removing field

Tags: python, django, migration, django-1.11

So I have a model in my Django project (for arguments sake called 'app'), for example;

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    fieldA = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and I can run python manage.py makemigrations app; which gives me

```
Migrations for 'app':
  app/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model ModelA
```

If I then add a new field to ModelA so it looks like;

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    fieldA = models.IntegerField(default=0),
    fieldB = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

and then run makemigrations again, I get;

```
Migrations for 'app':
  app/migrations/0002_auto_20170529_1737.py
    - Remove field fieldA from modela
    - Add field fieldB to modela
```

The auto-generated file backs this up;

```
operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='modela',
            name='fieldA',
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='modela',
            name='fieldB',
            field=models.IntegerField(default=1),
        ),
    ]
```

Why does it remove fieldA?

My understanding was that it should only script changes to the models, i.e. 
That fieldB has been added.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you added a comma to the `fielda` line when you added `fieldb`:

```
fieldA = models.IntegerField(default=0),
```

You should remove the comma and delete the `0002` migration. Then, when you rerun `makemigrations`, Django will no longer try to remove `fielda`.

Comment: *facepalm* Thank you, very much! That was so frustrating.

Comment: 4 years and a half later, this answer is still relevant and saved me from falling to alcohol and slowly go to live under a bridge. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see the whole class that countains your field but it appears that a field can be omitted or removed from the migration process if there is a @property method with the same name as your field.
The code below will thus remove fieldA from the database

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    fieldA = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    @property
    def fieldA(self):
        pass
```

and you should rename your field or your method :

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    _fieldA = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    @property
    def fieldA(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Excellent, this will certainly cause fields to be removed in a migration. Thank you!